# Show UISearchController on UITableView scroll down

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` just over my `UITableView` and my table has many recrods. When a user goes to bottom in the table, he has to come back to top to see the search bar. Below you can see how I create the search bar:

```
- (void) showSearchBar {
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    //self.sharedNavigationItem.titleView = _searchController.searchBar;

    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; // default is YES
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others
        self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

}
```

I was wondering how to show the search bar when I scroll down (go up) in the table and hide it back when I scroll up (go down) in the table even I am at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search bar can be placed arbitrarily in the UI.  Create a sibling view to the table view, placed -- for example -- above the table.  Give that view a height constraint set initially to 44px and provide outlets to both the view and the constraint...

```
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *searchBarContainerView;
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *searchBarHeightConstraint;
```

Now, your setup code changes to:

```
// ...
self.searchBarHeightConstraint.constant = self.searchController.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
[self.searchBarContainerView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the header stay at top, then the search field should stay visible

> **UITableViewStylePlain**: A plain table view. Any section headers or footers are displayed as inline separators and float when the table view is scrolled.
>
> **UITableViewStyleGrouped**: A table view whose sections present distinct groups of rows. The section headers and footers do not float.

Comment: This is good info.  So I guess the OP can set the style to plain and place the search bar in the section 0 header?  This is good to know, though it should be pointed out that this approach constrains other table behaviors (e.g.. the the OP wants something else in the section header, or doesn't want other headers to float, etc.)

Comment: he can define it to only a chosen table, this doesn't need to apply to all

Answer (score 0):

I trying to help you out with what I did, hope it helps you.
This is how I added my label in header view of table view, I tried to replace it by your search controller;

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40);
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = nil;
        [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
        [view addSubview:_searchController];
        view.tag = 123;
        return view;
}
```

If you wish to hide effect at complete end of dragging move use below method;

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                    withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
             targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    if (velocity.y > 0){
    NSLog(@"up");
    [self.view viewWithTag:123].hidden = true;
}
if (velocity.y < 0){
    NSLog(@"down");
    [self.view viewWithTag:123].hidden = false;
}
```

And for immediate changes of scrolling the tableview use below method :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView //working delegate
{
    if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView].y > 0) {
        NSLog(@"down");
        [self.view viewWithTag:123].hidden = false;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"up");
        [self.view viewWithTag:123].hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I thought of some new answer, hope it helps you!

To  identify direction of Scroll:

```
BOOL showSearch;

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView].y > 0) {
        // down
        showSearch = true;
    } else {
        // up
        showSearch = false;
    }
}

-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                    withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
             targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
     if (showSearch) {
         [self addSearch];
     }
     else {
         [self removeSearch];
     }
     [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

To add & remove SearchController:

```
-(void)addSearch {    
     if (!_searchController){

     _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [_searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;

    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    _searchController.active = NO;

    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;

    _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)removeSearch {
    _searchController.active = NO;
    [_searchController removeFromParentViewController];
    _searchController = nil;
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
}
```